# Unit testing testng's IReporter

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I am implementing IReporter to generate custom reports in my project. Now I am required to write unit test to test the reporting module, basically I have to check if the IReporter implementing class is called and to check if certaing methods are called.

example:

```
public class MyReporter implements IReporter{

@Override
public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory){

  //custom code
   method1();
  //custom code
}

public void method1(){

}

}
```

After execution of a test case, generateReport() is called and I want to verify the sequence of methods called. I can use Mockito framework to mock objects.

ANy help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What is the functionality that you need to test? just testing that method was called is not a good idea, instead find a business case/feature to test

Comment: I just need to verify that the IReporter's generateReport() is called after test execution.

Comment: So what is the problem - use Mockito

Comment: I figured it out, thanks! :)